# Im trying to return a string based on a value from a list

Tags: mysql

So I have a list of ID's that later put a string to describe the issue.

I want to filter these out by their id and display a string based on the primary id#

```
select
sol.solution `Solution`,
count(sol.id) `Solution Count`,
case sol.id when 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,25,29,33,37,40,41,42,48,51 then 'Hardware'
else 'Software' end `HW/SW`
from tickets t
   join ticket_solutions tsol
    on tsol.ticket_id =t.id
   join solutions sol
    on tsol.solution_id = sol.id
```

Comment: `SELECT` where is your `FROM` part?

Comment: explain better you question is not clear ..

Comment: its comming from 3 joined tables.

Comment: i have a list of SOL.id that if they are part of that list i would like to return with 'Hardware' otherwise they should be 'Software' im trying to do this with a case statement.

Comment: why do you select from `tickets` if you don't use any value from that table? I guess you should `COUNT(t.id)` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your description is not 100% clear here is just my guess:

```
SELECT
sol.solution `Solution`,
COUNT(t.id) `Solution Count`,
IF(sol.id IN (8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,25,29,33,37,40,41,42,48,51),'Hardware','Software') `HW_SW`
FROM tickets t
JOIN ticket_solutions tsol
  ON tsol.ticket_id =t.id
JOIN solutions sol
  ON tsol.solution_id = sol.id
GROUP BY sol.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The `case` expression in the shortened form doesn't take lists of values, just single values. You could, however, use the longer (condition-based) form with an `in` operator:

```
CASE WHEN sol.id IN (8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,25,29,33,37,40,41,42,48,51)  
     THEN 'Hardware'
     ELSE 'Software'
END AS `HW/SW`
```